# How can I speed up capturing stills with camera module v2 and picamera?

Tags: camera, picamera

Using some very simple code with no bells and whistles I capture shots of a specimen in between rotations of a motor

```py
camera = PiCamera(sensor_mode=2)
camera.exposure_mode = 'sports'
camera.resolution = (1536, 1536)
camera.led = False
FORMAT = 'png'

for step in range(n_steps):
    save_to = osp.join(
        dest, folder, f"{step:02d}_{uuid4()}.{FORMAT}")
    camera.capture(save_to, format=FORMAT)
    print(f"#{step} Photo captured and saved to {save_to}")
    motor.rotate(step_size)
```

The problem is that the line `camera.capture(save_to, format=FORMAT)` takes about 6 seconds per step. I don't understand why this should be the case, as preview mode seems to have something like a 15 fps frame rate.

Am I missing some configuration step to make sure these come out faster?

**EDIT**

Finally figured out that jpeg (`format='jpeg'`) encoding is way faster. Why though?